# Cannot add X and Y axis titles with Chart.min.js v3.0.0

Tags: javascript

I have been searching all day for how to title the x and y axes. The most common method is listed below and that is where I am at. It does everything it should except label the x and y axes.

```
      var ctx0 = document.getElementById('myChart0').getContext('2d');
      const plotData0 = {
         labels: [],
         datasets: [
            {
               data: [],
               borderColor: 'red',
               borderWidth: 2,
               tension: 0,
               fill: false
            }],
         };
         
         var myChart0 = new Chart(ctx0, {
         type: 'line',
         data: plotData0,
         options: {
            responsive: true,
            legend: {
               position: 'bottom'
            },
            scales: {
               xAxes: [{
                  display: true,
                  scaleLabel: {
                     display: true,
                     labelString: 'X-Axis Label'
                  }
               }],
               yAxes: [{
                  display: true,
                  scaleLabel: {
                     display: true,
                     labelString: 'Y-Axis Label'
                  }
               }],
            },
         }
      });
```

Sometimes the various labelling syntax I tried would introduce another set of Y scales. But otherwise I cannot see what else I can try. Any suggestions would be very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This change should fix the problem:

```js
var myChart0 = new Chart("myChart0", {
  type: "line",
  data: plotData0,
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      position: "bottom"
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        display: true,
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: "X-Axis Label"
        }
      },
      y: {
        display: true,
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: "Y-Axis Label"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that reply. However, it produced a display that I have now seen many times when trying to add axis labels - it adds another set of numbers to the left of the real Y axis numbers. These range from 0 to 1.0 and remain fixed as such while the actual Y axis numbers change to reflect the incoming values. I would not expect it to effect the display, but perhaps I should have shown the entire script. This consists of four charts each showing different data but which respond to the effects represented by the first chart. Doesn't seem to be any way to show that here without another post.